# jQuery set custom dimensions for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dimensions

I have a div which I would like to set custom dimensions using two text inputs.

```
<div id="theFrame"></div>
    width: <input id="custWidth" type="text">
    height: <input id="custHeight" type="text">
<br>
<button id="custSet">Set my width!</button>
```

I have tried setting the height and width with variables, but I am at a loss as to how to do it now.

```
var frame = $('div#theFrame');

$("#custWidth")
    .keyup(function () {
        var custWidth = $(this).attr('value');
    })
    .keyup();

$("#custHeight")
    .keyup(function () {
        var custHeight = $(this).attr('value');
    })
    .keyup();

$('#custSet')
    .click( function() {
        frame.css({height: custHeight, width: custWidth});
    });
```

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/6MUuv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably need to include 'px' when setting your CSS:

```
frame.css({height: custHeight + 'px', width: custWidth + 'px'});
```

Also, you need to define your custHeight and custWidth parameters globally, since they are local only in the key up function.

```
var frame = $('div#theFrame'), custWidth = 0, custHeight = 0;

$("#custWidth")
    .keyup(function () {
        window.custWidth = $(this).attr('value');
    })
    .keyup();
```

And... I believe you don't need the second keyup() call there:

```
$("#custWidth")
    .keyup(function () {
        window.custWidth = $(this).attr('value');
    });
```

Comment: If you use `frame.height(cutHeight)` and `frame.width(custWidht)` you don't need to worry about `px` as those jQuery methods always use pixels.

Answer (score 5):

```
var frame = $('div#theFrame');
var custWidth;
var custHeight;
$("#custWidth").keyup(function () {
      custWidth = $(this).attr('value');
    }).keyup();

$("#custHeight").keyup(function () {
      custHeight = $(this).attr('value');
    }).keyup();

$('#custSet').click( function() {
    frame.css({height: custHeight, width: custWidth});
});
```

your variable scope is off.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is those variables for the width and height are scoped. You need to define them outside the event handlers then set them in them without the `var` before them.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your variables in the outer scope:

```
var frame = $('div#theFrame');
var custWidth = 40;  // declared outside and assigned a default value
var custHeight = 40; // declared outside and assigned a default value

$("#custWidth").keyup(function () {
      custWidth = $(this).attr('value');
    }).keyup();

$("#custHeight").keyup(function () {
     custHeight = $(this).attr('value');
    }).keyup();

$('#custSet').click( function() {
    //frame.height(custHeight); // Alternative to .css() if you like, also doesn't need 'px' as it always is in pixels.
    //frame.width(custWidth);  // Alternative to .css() if you like, also doesn't need 'px' as it always is in pixels.
    frame.css({height: custHeight, width: custWidth});
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6MUuv/7/)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: Nice catch, copied the wrong URL after update :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the tow variables global custWidth,custHeight

```
var frame = $('div#theFrame');
var custWidth,custHeight ;
$("#custWidth").keyup(function () {
      custWidth = $(this).attr('value');
}).keyup();

$("#custHeight").keyup(function () {
      custHeight = $(this).attr('value');
}).keyup();

$('#custSet').click( function() {
    frame.css({height: custHeight, width: custWidth});
});
```